# Is there a way to minify HTML?

Tags: performance

Is there a way to minify HTML in Drupal 8, something like the [Minify](https://www.drupal.org/project/minify) module which is for Drupal 7?

Comment: What is the reason you want to minify the HTML?

Answer (score 4):

Use [spaceless](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html) tag. This will not minify the HTML, instead avoids extra whitespace between HTML tags to avoid browser rendering quirks. When cached, can serve better.

In **html.html.twig**

```
{% spaceless %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
 #rest of the code
</html>

{% endspaceless %}
```

For compression there is a [twig extension](https://packagist.org/packages/nochso/html-compress-twig)

**Edit**: Use [Minify Source HTML](https://www.drupal.org/project/minifyhtml) module which comes for both D7 and D8.

Comment: After applying this tag [Google Page SpeedInsights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insight) does not list html minification as a possible improvement anymore.

Comment: This tag will only remove extra whitespaces, this will not minify HTML but in some way helps in reducing page size and serves better when cached.

Answer (score 0):

The [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module has a minify feature:

> CSS/JS Compress Submodules. Can minifiy files & inline CSS/JS. Can also turn off core CSS compression for theme development.

Comment: There is a Advagg feature request for html minification https://www.drupal.org/node/2787385 and a sandbox project for a separate module https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/almare/2730729